Is there any fix to content getting cut off by other content on Power BI Paginated Report when exporting to pdf?
I am working in PowerBI Report Builder and having issues with the way that content is shown in my page header when exporting as a pdf. This report is supposed to be able to capture the needs of printed exports for various projects and filtered selections. The header has no formatting problems when exported as a pdf for default selections, but there seems to be a content limit that I can't track down when more selections are made.
This would be how our "default" header shows in the PowerBI preview: (https://i.sstatic.net/Wp2li6wX.png)
And with more "CWP" selections made, the PowerBI preview shows as this: (https://i.sstatic.net/OE8tI018.png) [actual "CWPs" were overlayed with text representing exactly what's happening]
This in theory is how we would like this to look and work. The only time that the header should expand is when there is more content to capture. We do not want to find a solution where the header initial size spans several rows to capture the maximum amount of content we would ever find it filling in here and leave it with a large blank space in the header section for our "default" header or when less filtered selections are being listed.
The issue arises when exporting as really any file type, but we use PDFs as the main export format. All content gets limited to 3 rows of text, no longer shows "Location" and is cut off by our table of our dataset below it.
(https://i.sstatic.net/TbwEbpJj.png)
We do not want to export as Excel to then manually adjust the header format and print to pdf. There are various other issues with how Excel prints/exports as pdf and cuts off other content from the data table below, which is the main content of the report. (Issue being what you see isn't what you'll always get)
Here is what this section of the report looks like in the design view:
(https://i.sstatic.net/8yXre2TK.png) All text boxes in this section have "Allow height to increase" selected.
Ultimately, we want to find a fix that captures all cases of how far the header should expand, and allow that size to adjust automatically when exporting to pdf.
Please let me know what additional context may be needed to help with this. TIA.

Yes if you want career ending platform, work with pbi paginated report builder :}
Report Builder pdf export treating headers as static
